# Что использовать для разработки под Windows?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Доброго времени суток!

Я хочу создать сервис видео-конференций для Windows 7/10/11. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно использовать, если нужно добиться максимальной производительности программы, минимального места занимаемой памяти и не слишком большой требовательности к железу.
Например: C++ или C# (если C++, то какой компилятор, а если C#, то .NET Core или .NET Framework), Visual Studio или Qt Creator, Qt или MAUI и т.д.

P.S. Уважаемые модераторы! Я понимаю, что на вопрос скорее всего нельзя дать однозначный ответ, однако прошу не блокировать мой вопрос (хотя бы пока я не получу ответы), потому что мне важно узнать разные ответы с обоснованиями. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: QT, конечно, вещь! Но она платная для коммерческой разработки. Следует это учитывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### IDE

Если пишете код под Windows на C++ или C#, лучше использовать Visual Studio. Последняя версия Visual Studio на текущий момент 2022. Для некоммерческой разработки, если пишете код для самообучения, или это проект с открытым исходным кодом, можно использовать бесплатную версию Community. Для коммерческой разработки с закрытым исходным кодом - есть платная версия Professional, я использую именно её.

Если разработка не под Windows, или не хочется платить за IDE, можно попробовать последнюю версию Visual Studio Code. Эта IDE полностью бесплатна, но содержит меньше функций и требует больше времени и специфических знаний для настройки.

##### Язык

C++ или C# - с точки зрения производительности готового приложения, совершенно не важно. Так как я пишу только на C# и .NET, расскажу именно про него.

Актуальная версия .NET - .NET 6, скоро выйдет .NET 7. Microsoft в каждый релиз вкладывают много сил в оптимизацию производительности .NET, а так же добавляют новых фукций C# и API в .NET, чтобы было как можно больше возможности писать очень быстрый и лёгкий по ресурсам код. Поэтому, .NET 6 в целом очень сильно быстрее, чем устаревший .NET Framework 4.x.

С совместимостью под указанные операционные системы у .NET 6 проблем нет. Но зависит от того, какие функции операционной системы требуется использовать, например если нужен HTTP/2 или TLS 1.2, то на Windows 7 должны быть установлены нужные сервисные обновления, иначе работать не будет.

На текущий момент самый современный UI движок под .NET - Windows App SDK (WinUI 3), но он несовместим с Windows 7 или 8. Полностью совместимым и весьма мощным является WPF, он тоже актуален, вам стоит взять именно этот набор библиотек для разработки. MAUI стоит взять, если нужна кроссплатформенность (Mac OS) или мобильная разработка.

##### Видео

Есть много разных библиотек для кодирования видео, есть встроенные в .NET, есть нативные типа ffmpeg, которые без труда подключаются как к нативным приложениям на C++, так и к CLR приложениям на C#. Поэтому конкретно в этом месте тоже разницы особой, на чем именно писать, нет.

**Итого:** Visual Studio 2022 + .NET 6 + WPF (+MVVM конечно же)

*Если бы я выбирал, на чём мне писать, то отказался бы от Win7, и взял бы Win App SDK. Именно этот UI движок сейчас активно развивается в Microsoft. На сегодняшний день сыроват, но активно допиливается, не считаю сыроватость проблемой. Само приложение будет весить и кушать немного больше, чем WPF, но если не собираетесь писать проект размером с Visual Studio, не стоит думать про память, эта величина больше зависит от начинки проекта, а не от его типа.*

Comment: Если этот ответ имеет проблемы с качеством, или я где-то не прав, вместе с постановкой минуса пожалуйста уточните, где я ошибся - обязательно исправлюсь. Всего-лишь пытаюсь помочь автору собрать информацию, делюсь своими знаниями. Минус без причины - признак дурачины, уважаемые модераторы.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное за столь развёрнутый ответ! Вы полностью ответили на мой вопрос. Спасибо Вам ещё раз! Очень помогли!

Comment: Aepot, я в Интернете прочитал, что C# - больше для UI. И сложные продукты (например ПО) лучше делать на C++. Так ли это?

Comment: @ДмитрийКраснов не так.

Comment: Aepot, понял. Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что на форуме не так много людей которые знают одновременно хорошо и C++ и C#, потому маловероятно, что вы получите действительно хороший ответ который может вам помочь определиться. Кто-то будет говорить C++/C# лучше, при этом не зная другого языка. Но ладно, всё выше - не ответ.

*Если хотите производительность* - C++

*Мало места* - всё зависит только от вас.

Тут важно понять, что C# позволит вам намного легче это реализовать, а C++ - работать будет быстрее. Тут вам уж придётся самим выбирать.

*Читайте далее если выбрали C++:*

Я использую visual studio 2019 и пишу на C++, потому рекомендую её. Просто установить, работает нормально.

Qtcreator и Qt это разное. Qtcreator это IDE, а Qt - фреймворк. Если ну очень хотите оптимизацию берите OpenGL, если вы не хотите расплавить себе мозг - sfml. А если и это вам не по душе - Qt.

Comment: _C++ - работать будет быстрее_ - весьма холиварный вопрос на текущий момент и сильно зависит от самого кода. Если бы вы написали это лет 5 назад, я бы согласился и откланялся.

Comment: Извиняюсь, если это так. Я на шарпе не пишу/писал. Потому просто загуглил. @aepot

Comment: Можно заглянуть [сюда](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/category/performance/) и по диагонали глянуть лонгриды от Stephen Toub, если интересно, он их раз в год при выходе очередной RC версии .NET выкладывает. То есть если сравнить старый проприетарный .NET Framework 4.x и новый опенсорцный .NET 6, то это огромная разница по перфу. А добавление секций `unsafe` кода в C# позволяют писать почти на C++ со всеми указателями прямо внутри шарпа в плоть до того что можно вручную выбрать между `malloc()` и `calloc()`.